# mpdf: vertical table is fine but horizontal is not showing

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I have to create two types of tables: One is like a register which is working fine and second is like a form which is not working. The heading on page is shown but the table is not displaying. I have used similar css and coding style in both.

Note: in case of multiple records, one table must be displayed on each page and each table should consume only one page, not more than that.

Below is my code:

```
<head>

<style>
    .atable tr th{
        background-color: #FF0000;

    }
    .atable tr td{
        background-color: #FF0000;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<?php
if($result1 = $mysqli->prepare($qry))
{
    //parameters are bound here
if($result1->execute())
{
$finrest=$result1->get_result();
$a='<style>@page {
 margin: 10pt;
}</style>';

if ($finrest->num_rows > 0) 
{
 while($row= $finrest->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
  $gdImage = 'Images/img.jpg';

  $a.='<h4>PAGE TITLE</h4><table width="100%" style="overflow: wrap" style="border: 1px solid black;">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;">SECTION TITLE</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c0'] . '</font></td><td rowspan="4">' .  '<div id="testimage"><img src="' . $gdImage . '" width="80pt" /></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c1'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c2'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c3'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'.  $row['c4'] .'</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c5'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c6'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c7'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c8'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c9'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c10'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c11'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c12'] . ', ' .$row['c13'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c14'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c15'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;">SECTION TITLE</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c16'] . '</font></td><td rowspan="4">' .  '<div id="testimage"><img src="' . $gdImage . '" width="80pt" /></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c17'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c18'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c19'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c20'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title/CGPA</td><td>'. $row['c21'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;">SECTION TITLE</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c22'] . '</font></td><td rowspan="4">' .  '<div id="testimage"><img src="' . $gdImage . '" width="80pt" /></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c23'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c24'] . ', ' . $row['c26'] .'</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c25'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c27'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c28'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c29'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c30'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><font face="arial">Column Title</td><td>'. $row['c32'] . '</font></td>
     </tr>';
     //echo $a;
    //exit;
  }
 }
 else 
 {
 echo "0 results";
 }
 $a.='</table>';
 } 
}
$mysqli->close();

include("\mpdf\mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('','A4');
$mpdf->simpleTables = true;
$mpdf->packTableData = true;
$keep_table_proportions = TRUE;
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=1;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($a);
$mpdf->Output('mytable.pdf', 'D');
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the following table closing table inside the loop other wise you are getting tables inside tables.

```
$a.='</table>';
```

This will work for you 100%.

Comment: Perfect solution.